# Suppose $v, x \in V$ and $U, W \subseteq V$ such that $v + U = x + W$. Prove that $U = W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> $V$ is a vector space. Suppose $v, x \in V$ and $U, W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $v + U = x + W$. Prove that $U = W$.

I really have no idea where to start with this. In fact, after looking at the answer, it still makes little sense. The answer starts with:

> Note that $v + U = x + W$, hence $v = x + w_1$ where $w_1 \in W$.

I do not understand how they have made this step.

Comment: $v\in v+U=x+W$ so $v=x+w$ for some $w\in W$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $0\in U$ we have $v\in v+U= x+W$ so $v-x\in W$. Similary we have $x-v\in U$.

Now take any $u\in U$ then $v+u\in v+U = x+W$ so $v+u-x\in W$ so $$u=\underbrace{(v+u-x)}_{\in W} -\underbrace{(v-x)}_{\in W}  \in W$$ and thus $U\subseteq W$.

Similary we have $W\subseteq U$ and so $U=W$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $U=\{a-b:a,b\in x+U\}$ etc.